# How do I inquire about a missing email just after I got the job?

Tags: communication, hiring-process

So a company made me an offer a couple of days ago! They asked me to sign and return a PIIA, the offer letter, and a background check release. The hiring manager at the company said that after he received the forms, he would send me an email through Talentwise asking me to complete my background check. Furthermore, there's a deadline for tomorrow - after the end of business hours, the offer becomes null and void. I turned in the forms more than 24 hours ago, but so far there's been no Talentwise email!

How do I ask about the missing email without coming off as pushy or demanding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Dear xxx,

I have sent the email with the information you requested, and wanted to make sure it reached you. I am very excited about the opportunity and want to ensure that you receive my information so I can start on the date you requested. Thank you and have a great day!"